# Get thread index from a multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, threadpool

I'm using a library whose multiprocessing is implemented using `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool(processes)`.

How is it possible to get/compute the **thread index** from the pool (starting from `0` to `processes-1`) ?

I've been reading the documentation and searching the web without finding convincing solution. I can get the thread ID (using `threading.get_ident()`), and could go through all the threads to construct a mapping between their index and their ID but I would need to use some kind of `time.sleep()` to ensure I browse them all... Do you think of any better solution?

Comment: What's this for? Debug logging?

Comment: (construct a mapping is not a bad idea if there's really no API to do it. But you don't need to sleep, just wait until there are `processes` entries in the map. Be careful with the lox)

Comment: nope, assigning different generic resources to each thread (like GPU ;-) )

Comment: How can I be sure the thread are not taken twice?

Comment: Sorry, it is not really clear what result you expect. The workers in a pool are transient, you have no guarantee at all that they exist or even continue existing at any given time. If you already have some working code that produces the desired result, showing that might clear up what you practically expect; then again, this might be more appropriate for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) – be sure to check their [question guide](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2436/how-to-get-the-best-value-out-of-code-review-asking-questions) first, though.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, thanks for your replay. I don't have a working code, it's just a supposition. Maybe I should rephrase the question: Is it possible to assign an index [0,N[ to each process executed through a `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool(N)` ?

Comment: actually, the implementation I was thinking of is exactly the implementation from @Booboo ... I just wanted to avoid the dummy job with a `time.sleep()`

Comment: @MisterMiyagi When you create the pool instance, you *can* specify a `maxtasksperchild` argument. But if you *don't*, the inference is that once a worker thread or process (as the case may be) is created for the pool, it continues to be used until the pool no longer exists and therefore the id/index mapping should remain valid.

Comment: @Booboo As far as I understand the description, the pool is created internally by the library. So whether it does use ``maxtasksperchild`` or not, and whether it *will*, is probably not guaranteed. Still, I guess for practical cases that is not relevant.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi The docs say: **`maxtasksperchild` is the number of tasks a worker process can complete before it will exit and be replaced with a fresh worker process, to enable unused resources to be freed. The default `maxtasksperchild` is None, which means worker processes will live as long as the pool.** What is unclear about that?

Comment: @Booboo I was referring to the description *of the question*, not the Python documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to get the index of the thread in the ThreadPool without using sleep, by using the initializer function. This is a function that is called once immediately after the thread is started. It can be used to acquire resources, such as a database connection, to use exactly one connection per thread.

Use `threading.local()` to make sure that each thread can store and access its own resource. In the example below we treat the index in the ThreadPool as a resource. Use a Queue to make sure no two threads grab the same resource.

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
import threading
import time
import queue

POOL_SIZE = 4
local_storage = threading.local()

def init_thread_resource(resources):
    local_storage.pool_idx = resources.get(False)
    print(f'\nThread {threading.get_ident()} has pool_idx {local_storage.pool_idx}')
    ## A thread can also initialize other things here, meant for only 1 thread, e.g.
    # local_storage.db_connection = open_db_connection()

def task(item):
    # When running this example you may see all the tasks are picked up by one thread. 
    # Uncomment time.sleep below to see each of the threads do some work.
    # This is not required to assign a unique index to each thread.
    # time.sleep(1)
    return f'Thread {threading.get_ident()} with pool_idx {local_storage.pool_idx} handled {item}'

def run_concurrently():
    # Initialize the resources
    resources = queue.Queue(POOL_SIZE)  # one resource per thread
    for pool_idx in range(POOL_SIZE):
        resources.put(pool_idx, False)
    container = range(500, 500 + POOL_SIZE)  # Offset by 500 to not confuse the items with the pool_idx
    with ThreadPool(POOL_SIZE, init_thread_resource, [resources]) as pool:
        records = pool.map(task, container)
    print('\n'.join(records))

run_concurrently()
```

This outputs:

```
Thread 32904 with pool_idx 0 handled 500
Thread 14532 with pool_idx 1 handled 501
Thread 32008 with pool_idx 2 handled 502
Thread 31552 with pool_idx 3 handled 503
```

Answer (score 2):

The idea is to create a worker function, called `test_worker` in the example below, that returns its thread identity and the argument it is called with, which takes on values of 0 ... pool size - 1. We then submit tasks with:

```py
pool.map(test_worker, range(POOLSIZE), 1)
```

By specifying a `chunksize` value of 1, the idea is that each thread will be given just 1 task to process with the first thread given argument 0, the second thread argument 1, etc. We must ensure that `test_worker` gives up control of the processor to the other threads in the pool. If it were to consist only of a `return` statement, the first thread might end up processing all the tasks. Essentially tasks are placed on a single queue in lists of `chunksize` tasks and each pool thread takes off the next available list and processes the tasks in the list, But if the task is so trivial, it is possible that the first thread could actually grab all the lists because it never gives up control of the processor to the other threads. To avoid this, we insert a call to `time.sleep` in our worker.

```py
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
import threading


def test_worker(i):
    # To ensure that the worker gives up control of the processor we sleep.
    # Otherwise, the same thread may be given all the tasks to process.
    time.sleep(.1)
    return threading.get_ident(), i

def real_worker(x):
    # return the argument squared and the id of the thread that did the work
    return x**2, threading.get_ident()

POOLSIZE = 5
with ThreadPool(POOLSIZE) as pool:
    # chunksize = 1 is critical to be sure that we have 1 task per thread:
    thread_dict = {result[0]: result[1]
                   for result in pool.map(test_worker, range(POOLSIZE), 1)}
    assert(len(thread_dict) == POOLSIZE)
    print(thread_dict)
    value, id = pool.apply(real_worker, (7,))
    print(value) # should be 49
    assert (id in thread_dict)
    print('thread index = ', thread_dict[id])
```

Prints:

```
{16880: 0, 16152: 1, 7400: 2, 13320: 3, 168: 4}
49
thread index =  4
```

**A Version That Does Not Use `sleep`**

```py
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
import threading
import time

def test_worker(i, event):
    if event:
        event.wait()
    return threading.get_ident(), i

def real_worker(x):
    return x**2, threading.get_ident()


# Let's use a really big pool size for a good test:
POOLSIZE = 500
events = [threading.Event() for _ in range(POOLSIZE - 1)]
with ThreadPool(POOLSIZE) as pool:
    thread_dict = {}
    # These first POOLSIZE - 1 tasks will wait until we set their events
    results = [pool.apply_async(test_worker, args=(i, event)) for i, event in enumerate(events)]
    # This last one is not passed an event and so it does not wait.
    # When it completes, we can be sure the other tasks, which have been submitted before it
    # have already been picked up by the other threads in the pool.
    id, index = pool.apply(test_worker, args=(POOLSIZE - 1, None))
    thread_dict[id] = index
    # let the others complete:
    for event in events:
        event.set()
    for result in results:
        id, index = result.get()
        thread_dict[id] = index
    assert(len(thread_dict) == POOLSIZE)
    value, id = pool.apply(real_worker, (7,))
    print(value) # should be 49
    assert (id in thread_dict)
    print('thread index = ', thread_dict[id])
```

Prints:

```
49
thread index =  499
```

Comment: So you don't see a way to avoid the sleep ? (that doesn't give a guarantee that one thread is not used twice)

Comment: I've tried this with thread pool size of 500 and `assert(len(thread_dict) == POOLSIZE)`  *asserted True* without a problem. But there are very few guarantees in life except for death and taxes. The larger the `sleep` argument, the greater the certainty I would think.

Comment: I've updated with an additional version that you might like better.